# React native not building on android - gradle build problem on ndk abiFilters

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error while I try to build a react native application using cmd: cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Conflicting configuration : 'armeabi-v7a,x86' in ndk abiFilters cannot be present when splits abi filters are set : x86,armeabi-v7a

Here I have commented the ndk part of the code in my build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.beonews"
      minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
      targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
      versionCode 22
      versionName "2.8.4"
     // ndk {
    //      abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    // }


  splits {
      abi {
          reset()
          enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
          universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal 
          APK
          //  include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
         }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your whole build.gradle please? and don't comment the ndk lines please

Comment: Don't comment `include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"` under splits. And try ./gradlew clean before building.